# Как лучше считать данные из консоли?

Tags: java, консоль

Решаю олимпиадные задачки [такого рода](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1038) на java. Сам алгоритм решения задачи я написал. Возникла проблема с тем как лучше организовать считывание данных из консоли. Если делать так:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(); 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String temp;
while ((temp = sc.nextLine()).length() > 0){
    text.append(temp);
}

/*code*/
```

то выполнение происходит только после чтения пустой строчки. Если использовать `sc.hasNext()`, то последующий код вообще не выполняется. Если читать с помощью InputReader-а, то пока он не считает 10000 символов, программа не продолжит работу. 
Как посоветуете решить данную проблему?

Comment: > то выполнение происходит только после
> чтения пустой строчки

Логично, потому что длинна пустой строчки равна 0. А как еще вы хотите отличать конец ввода от ввода следующей строки?

Comment: Да, я в принципе понимаю, что логично. Для этого и привел конкретную задачу. Как в ней организовать чтение?

Comment: на регулярках задача решается в несколько строк :)

Comment: А вас интересует именно как входной поток считать в строку, или как его потом на токены разбить?

Comment: Я думаю как бы так сделать, чтобы когда вводишь тестовые данные ("`This sentence iz correkt! -It Has,No mista;.Kes et oll.
But there are two BIG mistakes in this one!
and here is one more.`") из задания и нажимаешь enter продолжилось выполнение программы без ожидания пустой строки.

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает нажимать Cltr+C (окончание потока) вместо этого?

Comment: На самом деле нажимать-то буду не я, а автоматическая программа проверки. И насколько я понял она будет вводить тестовые наборы данных нажатием клавиши `enter`, хотя я могу и ошибаться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала про заблуждения:

- Автоматическая программа проверки на Тимусе вводит данные не "нажатием клавиши enter". Она просто отправляет текстовый файл во входной поток вашей программы. Получив последнюю строчку, следующий вызов `sc.nextLine()` не зависнет, как при вашем ручном тестировании, а наткнётся на конец потока и выбросит `NoSuchElementException`.
- Версия с `sc.hasNext()` не переходила к дальнейшему коду, потому что вы отправляли ей пустые строчки, а нужно было отправлять символ конца потока. Хоткей для него варьируется в зависимости от того где вы запускаете программу. В Windows cmd это, например, `Ctrl + Z`

В итоге можете использовать либо версию с `hasNext()` либо следующий грязный трюк.

```
String input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

`\\A` -- это символ начала потока.

Ещё [на тимусе предлагают](http://acm.timus.ru/help.aspx?topic=java) для удобства тестирования проверять, запущено ли решение на локальной машине, и тогда брать данные из файла:

```
Scanner sc = System.getProperty("ONLINE_JUDGE") != null
           ? new Scanner(System.in)
           : new Scanner(new File("your_file.txt");
String input = sc.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```